# Failed to call the browser based request using PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, php-curl

If we call the same URL in the browser then it auto-download the CSV file. So, I want the same feature using PHP curl to save the CSV file under the same folder. But it gives me an empty result every time. Can you please guide me on what's is wrong in the code below?

```
$url="https://www.centrano.com/catalog_download.php?email=info@sporttema.com&password=dHB3L1FpTEg1c2pLZ29SUkdnUWcwWTFqN2RIamQx";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$agent= "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100000); //time out of 15 seconds
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
print_r($output);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following two CURL options to make it work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);                                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
```

The page redirects several times to the same host and requires for the session cookies to remain present (thus, storing them in a cookie jar.

Also: **change your centrano.com account password IMMEDIATELY!** Even though it helped solving this, it's generally not a good idea to make it public.